# Is there a chance to achieve partial subequations in align?

Tags: align, subequations

I want to align four equations. I want the first and the second to be *regularly tagged*, and the third and the fourth to be *subtagged*. Is there a chance to achieve that by using `align` and `subequations`? Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        \mathbf{a}_{p}^{\mathsf{t}} &= A \\
        \mathbf{a}_{q}^{\mathsf{r}} &= B \\
        \mathbf{a}_{k,l} & = C \\
                         & = D
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

I want the first equation to be tagged with **(1)**, the second to be tagged with **(2)**, the third and the fourth to be tagged with **(3a)** and **(3b)**, respectively. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not fully automated, I'm afraid.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sublabel}[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}\ltx@label{#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{a}_{p}^{\mathsf{t}} &= A \\
\mathbf{a}_{q}^{\mathsf{r}} &= B \\
\mathbf{a}_{k,l} & = C \sublabel{partial}\tag{\ref*{partial}a}\label{partial-a}\\
                 & = D \tag{\ref*{partial}b}
\end{align}

Another equation to check numbering is OK
\begin{equation} \label{x}
1=1
\end{equation}

\ref{partial-a} and \ref{x} and \ref{partial}

\end{document}
```

If you don't plan to use `hyperref`, change `\ref*` into `\ref`.

[image]